# Jmeter recorded script is not added data on frontend side

Tags: server, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I recorded my **jmeter** script on server x and make it dynamic after that run that same script on server y - it fetch all data by post processor and did not give any error but data is not added on fronted . how can I solve it any reason behind it? (website is same just change the server for testing)

**expected**-Data should add on fronted like create lead on server y (successfully create on server x)

**actual** -data not added on server y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you need to [correlate your script](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) as it is not doing what it is supposed to be doing.

You can run your test with 1 virtual user and 1 iteration configured in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and inspect request and response details using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

My expectation is that you either not getting logged in (you have added [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan, haven't you?) or fail to provide valid dynamic parameters. Modern web applications widely use dynamic parameters for example for [client side state tracking](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/225740/what-is-view-state-and-how-it-works-in-Asp-Net53/) or for [CSRF protection](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md#synchronizer-token-pattern)

You can easily detect dynamic parameters by recording the same scenario one more time and compare the generated scripts. All the values which differ need to be correlated, to wit extracted from the previous response using a suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and stored into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html). Once done you will need to replace recorded hard-coded value with the aforementioned JMeter Variable.

Check out [How to Handle Correlation in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/) article for comprehensive information with examples.